# Swift 4 Codable : Common struct for all model

Tags: ios, swift, swift4, codable

Here i am getting API response of all of my api.

```
{
  "success" : true,
  "message" : "",
  "data" : {
        /multipal data parameter/ 
   }
}
```

And here is my codable model

```
struct Login: Codable {
    let success: Bool
    let message: String
    let data: Data

    struct Data: Codable  {

    }
}
```

How can i create common **Sturct** for **success** and **message** parameter.

Comment: if success and message come in another dictionary then it can be do

Comment: Login _is_ a "common struct for `success` and `message` parameter".

Comment: @matt and what for other parameter, any example would be helpful

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make the root struct representing the network response generic, this will allow you to keep the `success` and `message` parts common between all specialised responses.

```
struct NetworkResponse<ResponseData:Codable>: Codable {
    let success: Bool
    let message: String
    let data: ResponseData
}
```

You shouldn't create custom types with the same name as built in types, since that will lead to confusion, especially for other people reading your code, so I renamed your custom `Data` type to `ResponseData`.

For instance you can create a `LoginResponse` model and decode it like below. You can do the same for other responses from the same API.

```
let loginResponse = """
{
    "success" : true,
    "message" : "",
    "data" : {
        "username":"test",
        "token":"whatever"
    }
}
"""

struct LoginResponse: Codable {
    let username: String
    let token: String
}

do {
    print(try JSONDecoder().decode(NetworkResponse<LoginResponse>.self, from: Data(loginResponse.utf8)))
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Comment: Generic would be good but how to decode response with generics with NetworkResponse

Comment: @BhaveshDhaduk check my updated answer I've added an example

Comment: @AshleyMills `ResponseData` is a type itself, which conforms to `Codable`, so in the custom initialiser of `NetworkResponse`, you can simply decode `ResponseData` just like you would for a non-generic type conforming to `Codable`.

Answer (score 0):

**Common structure :**

[image: My common struture of model]

**I have created something like that**

```
struct statusModel<T:Codable>: Codable {

    let message : String
    let resultData : [T]?
    let status : Int

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case message = "message"
        case resultData = "resultData"
        case status = "status"
    }
}
```

**Regular model (resultData)**

```
struct modelInitialize : Codable {

    let profileimgurl : String?
    let projecturl : String?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case profileimgurl = "profileimgurl"
        case projecturl = "projecturl"
    }
}
```

You can set like as below

```
    do {
        guard let reponseData = responseData.value else {return} //Your webservice response in Data
        guard let finalModel = try?JSONDecoder().decode(statusModel<modelInitialize>.self, from: reponseData) else {return}
       }
```

Comment: How to pass optional T parameter to statusModel?

Comment: just don't pass the statusmodel and pass only "modelInitialize.self"